# Should one stop loading UIView from xibs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Since the time iOS 5.0 has brought the concept of childViewControllers, Its seems that it can do everything, I am used to doing with UIView that I used to load from xib files.

Scenario's where I would generally use a UIView and have it contain everything else from the xib file. If there are any Delegate and DataSources needed to be implemented that a UIView used to load.

Using Something like this:

```
 NSArray* nibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ABCustomLoginView" owner:self options:nil];
        if(nibsArray && [nibsArray count] > 0)        {
            self = [[nibsArray objectAtIndex:0] retain];
        }
```

This never seemed correct, It used to break MVC. 
Why would a UIView handle events of another UIView ?

Now that childViewController's are there, Should I always make a decently sized fragment of UI which has its own functionality and can be re-used later into a separate UIViewController ?

Or there are situations where the previous method still has an upper-hand ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use child view controllers when you are building custom container view controllers, or your layout is very complex.

Now for my opinion: I always use storyboards, because they allow you to express an entire screen all at design time without having to assemble it (like your code above) at runtime.

So, even if you choose to use a storyboard for each individual view controller (some large teams do this to avoid merge problems), you can have all of your views and view controller laid out and connected together.

If you are looking to create a dynamic number of a certain view at runtime, I probably would just code the view, or if its very complex, I'd store an NSNib in an ivar and instantiate each view from it.

Bottom line: child view controllers in no way replace or are even related to your code sample of how you use to do it.

Comment: I am talking about scenario where you have a re-usable part of your screen which you reuse in multiple screens.
Its common in iPad applications.

to use it at multiple places and to avoid coding its UI , I used to use a nib and load that nib as a subview of a customView.
In most cases if that view had a tableView, the customView would handle the delegates of tableView.
In scenarios like this, wont childViewControllers be a perfect choice ?
its similar to concept of fragments in android.

Comment: I see. Yes, thats a valid application for child view controllers. You're correct in your original question that views should not handle other views events, so in this case, a child view controller would own its view and handle its events. (I would still load the child view controller from a storyboard). If youre a small team, i would have it all in one storyboard and point all your child view container objects to the "scene" that is your child view controller used in multiple places.

Comment: Fine. story board is fine. I am not arguing about storyboard or xib. my argument was choosing between UIViews and childViewControllers.

Although storyboard is something I am yet to use in a project, I am afraid of git conflicts that may come if multiple people try to mess with the storyboards.
It is just one file for whole project. right ?
Even if we break it down into multiple storyboards, then we lose the purpose of using storyboards itself.

Comment: No, storyboards have many advantages to xibs, even if you use a different storyboard for each view controllers. Most people split their app into a few storyboards, one for each logical section of the app, like settings. The reason i brought up storyboards is because you were asking about proper MVC separation, storyboards help with that. I also confirmed that using child view controllers in the scenario described was indeed more appropriate than a subview whos events are managed by the superview.

Comment: Sure. I will definitely try using story boards.